# How to reduce the chewiness of fruit leather

Tags: texture, consistency, fruit-leather

I have found out quite a lot on [fruit leathers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/26157/what-am-i-trying-to-cook-i-need-the-name-of-the-dish-or-technique/26158).  I have researched on Google about them but from my research it appears everyone loves the fact they're nice and chewy and I can't find any website which explains why they're chewy.

My issue is, when I do them with passion fruit, they are far too chewy (as in they get stuck in your teeth). The only other ingredient I use is the fruit and sugar, but I do let it reduce in a pan first.

How can I make the fruit leather less chewy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What am I trying to cook - I need the name of the dish or technique](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/26157/what-am-i-trying-to-cook-i-need-the-name-of-the-dish-or-technique)

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/26159/3203

Comment: I had already (several hours before hand) mentioned this in my answer to this question?

Comment: Have you considered just not drying it as completely? I have a friend with false teeth, and that is what she does for her fruit leathers. Maintaining a bit of moisture makes for a softer, less clingy leather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has now been posted on my other question

[What is the name of this dish involving fruit & sugar - blended and baked thin and flat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/26157/what-am-i-trying-to-cook-i-need-the-name-of-the-dish-or-technique/26158)

It is by adjusting the sugar level.